# Knockout Component Template Rendered as Plain Text in Firefox

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a knockout component declared like this:

```
ko.components.register('promocode-box', {
    viewModel: { require: 'foo/promocode-box-viewmodel' },
    template: { require: 'text!foo/promocode-box-template.html' }
});
```

RequireJS as well as the text plugin are both loaded and configured like this:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'https://foo.com/js/'
});
define('knockout', ko);
```

I then use it in the page with a custom element:

```
<promocode-box params="foo: 'bar', baz: 'foobar'"></promocode-box>
```

Now what happens is that in every browser, the component renders correctly, but firefox (tested on v. 57.0.4) shows the component template's source code as 
plain text in the page, instead of rendering the component as expected.

Does anyone have any pointers as to what could be the issue here?

Comment: Have you checked Firefox'  developer console for error messages?

Comment: @connexo yes, there are no errors logged